# Are such assumptions of functions similar to strong convexity reasonable in convex optimization?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For $\mu$-strongly convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$, the following property holds: for any given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we have
$$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^\top(x-y) \ge \mu \|x-y\|^2.$$

I am thinking if the following statements are reasonable assumptions of functions to be analyzed in some optimization algorithms:

(I) There exists $\mu>0$ such that
$$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^\top D(x-y) \ge \mu \|x-y\|^2,$$
where $D$ is any $d\times d$ positive semidefinite matrix with bounded eigenvalues, $i.e.$, there exists $0<m\le M <\infty$ such that $mI \preceq D \preceq MI.$

(II) There exists $\mu>0$ such that
$$
((\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1}\nabla f(x) - (\nabla^2 f(y))^{-1}\nabla f(y))^\top(x-y) \ge \mu \|x-y\|^2.$$

(III) There exists $\mu>0$ such that $$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^\top (\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1}(x-y) \ge \mu \|x-y\|^2,$$

I am wondering if any of the above properties can be a common assumption in papers or if there are some related optimization papers that add such property as an assumption.